# IE8: Translucent background color but opaque background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, background-color

I have a loading div, with a loading symbol as the background image. I'd like that loading symbol to be completely opaque. However, in order to fade the page that is loading, I've set the background image to have an 80% opacity. This works well in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE8 the loading symbol is also translucent. Is there any way to fade the background color but not the background image in ie8?

The CSS:

```
#loadingDiv {
    background: url(../../images/Loading32.gif) no-repeat center center;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
    position: absolute;
    height: 330px;
    width: 890px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#88ffffff, endColorstr=#88ffffff)";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support `rgba`, so that's the reason it's not opaque...

So use a transparent background image probably using a 2x2 pixel image... Or

You can have a look at [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for IE8 support

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, IE8- doesn't support rgba, and neither do they support the CSS opacity rule. Personally, I'd create a translucent 1px png image, and repeat it as the background image.

First, create and place your transparent 1px png in your image directory. Name it 'translucentBG.png'.

Secondly, target IE with a separate stylesheet by putting the following in your source code's head:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then, create a file called 'all-ie-only.css' inside your css directory. Within 'all-ie-only.css', create this rule:

```
.loadingdiv {
    background: url(../../images/translucentBG.png);
}
```